# Eigenstates of operators on constituent systems in tensor product space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, tensor-calculus, eigenvalue

Suppose I have two entangled physical systems $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ with respective hilbert spaces  $\mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{A}}$ and $\mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{B}}$. If $A,B$ are operators on $\mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{A}}$ and $\mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{B}}$ respectively, then the operator $A\otimes B$ acting on $\mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{A}}\otimes\mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{B}}$ is defined by linear extension of the following action on the basis states $\lvert e_{\mathcal{A}}\rangle \otimes \lvert e_{\mathcal{B}}\rangle$
\begin{equation}(A\otimes B)(\lvert e_{\mathcal{A}}\rangle \otimes \lvert e_{\mathcal{B}})=(A\lvert e_{\mathcal{A}}\rangle ) \otimes (B\lvert e_{\mathcal{B}}\rangle)
\end{equation}
The operator corresponding to $A$ in the tensor product space is the operator $A\otimes \mathbb{I}_{\mathcal{B}}$, where $\mathbb{I}_{\mathcal{B}}$ is the identity operator on $\mathcal{B}$. I feel like the eigenstates of this operator should be $\lvert i\rangle \otimes \lvert\psi_B\rangle$ where $A\lvert i\rangle=i\lvert i\rangle$. The problem is I can't show this.

Comment: act with the operator $A\otimes B$ on the state, then if the result is proportional to the state itself you have proved that it is indeed an eigenstate.

Comment: Can I show there aren't any others though?

Comment: You will have as many eigenvectors as there are dimensions in your Hamiltonian (unless you have degeneracy in the eigenvalues which will complicate things slightly).

Comment: Crossposted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1194378/11127